# Vmplayer VM unroutable to VirtualBox VMs In The Same Subnet (and vice versa)

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

I'm running into an issue where I have Vmplayer and VirtualBox VMs both bridged, using dhcp, reaches the external network, and other hosts on the network can ping all the VMs. However, Vmplayer VMs and VirtualBox VMs can't ping each other.

These are the test results:

Vmplayer VMs *can* ping other Vmplayer VMs

VirtualBox VMs *can* ping other VirtualBox VMs

Other hosts can ping *both* Vmplayer VMs and VirtualBox VMs

Vmplayer VMs *can't* ping VirtualBox VMs

VirtualBox VMs *can't* ping Vmplayer VMs

[image: Vmplayer Network Settings]
[image: VirtualBox Network Settings]

Comment: Is your host connected thru wifi or ethernet?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the host is connected through ethernet

Comment: If you have a chance to make it work, it is by allowing promiscuous mode for all. Let me know whether this works, otherwise I will explain why it does not.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I just set Promiscuous Mode on VirtualBox for all. Both pings still timeout. How come it doesn't work?